# Sitecore PowerShell script to get all images where the media attached is empty

Tags: powershell-extensions

I'm writing a Sitecore PowerShell script to get all images (without their Media Folders) under the path `master:\sitecore\media library`, where the Media attached is empty.

I am using the below code but its not working:

```
$path = "master:\sitecore\media library"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Fields["Media"]))}

$items | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host "Item name: " $_.Name  $_.Paths.FullPath
}
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: basically its not working

Comment: [yourItem]._Fields["Media"] is a Field not a string

Comment: so, what needs to be written here

Comment: try to use `$_.Fields["Media"].value`

Comment: But its not value. It is whether attachment is there or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a post by Michael west to find the blob value from the image. Just try to reuse it. https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/edf8154f8fb4b8d2636390ba76707a48

```
$path = "/sitecore/media library/Project/Hackathon/Sitecore Hackathon"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -ne
[Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder }
$items | ForEach-Object {
  $mediaItem = [Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem]$_
  $blobField = $mediaItem.InnerItem.Fields["blob"]
  if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($blobField))
  {
      Write-Host "Empty Blob Item : "  $_.Name  $_.Paths.FullPath
  }
}
```

Just a suggestion. Please ask such type of questions in Slack channel #SPE.